# Ordering posts by metadata

Tags: plugin-development, custom-field, get-posts, post-meta

In my plugin, I use these instructions to obtain a list of posts:

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts'     => -1,
    'offset'          => 0,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'metadata1',
            'value' => '80',
            'compare' => '<=',
            'type' => 'UNSIGNED'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'metadata2',
            'value' => '4.6',
            'compare' => '<=',
            'type' => 'DECIMAL'
        ),
    ),
    'post_type'       => 'post',
    'post_status'     => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true );

$posts = get_posts($args);

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    // some work on $post
}
```

How can I order these posts by `metadata1` ascending or by `metadata2` ascending? (Note that `metadata1` is an unsigned integer number, and `metadata2` is a decimal number.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try meta_value_num

```
'meta_key' => 'metadata1',
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
```

Add these 2 parameters to $args. This does the sorting considering metadata1 as numeric

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you can't get this to work with get_posts, I'd recommend switching to [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).

As Mridul said above, to sort based on numbers, you need to specify the `'meta_value_num'` to `'orderby'` parameter. However, I'm not certain that you can do this with a standard `get_posts()` call.